# NodaTime TimeZone Data files naming

Tags: nodatime

It *appears* that the time zone database files used by Nodatime are named by year, with releases within the same year incrementing  by a 
letter - i.e., "tzdb2019a.nzd" is current as I write this, the next release 
will be "tzdb2019b.nzd", and some of the previous versions may have been 
"tzdb2018a.nzd", "tzdb2018b.nzd", "tzdb2018c.nzd", etc.

However, I have not been able to find this naming convention formally documented anywhere, and assumptions make me nervous.

I expect the time zone data to change more often than my application 
is updated, so the application periodically checks for the latest data file at
https://nodatime.org/tzdb/latest.txt, and downloads a new file if the one in 
use is different. Eventually there will be several files locally  available.

I want to know that I can sort these by name and be assured that I can 
identify the most recent from among those that have already been 
downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I *anticipate*, certainly. We use the versioning from the [IANA time zone page](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), just with a `tzdb` prefix and a `.nzd` suffix. So far, that's been enough, and it has maintained the sort order.

It's *possible* that we might want to provide other files at some point, e.g. if there's no IANA changes for a long time (as if!) but the CLDR Windows mapping files change significantly. I don't have any concrete plans for what I'd do in that case, but I can imagine something like `tzdb2019-2.nzd` etc.

It's hard to suggest specific mitigations against this without knowing the exact reason for providing other files, but you could potentially *only* download files if they match a regex of `tzdb\d{4}[a-z]+.nzd`.

I'd certainly communicate on the [Noda Time discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/noda-time) before doing anything like this, so if you subscribe there you should get advance warning.

Another nasty possibility that we might need more than 26 releases in a single calendar year... IANA says that would go 2020a...2020z, then 2020za...2020zz etc. The above regex handles that situation, and it stays sortable in the normal way.

Another option I could provide is an XML or JSON format for "all releases" - so just like there's https://nodatime.org/tzdb/index.txt that just lists the files, I could provide https://nodatime.org/tzdb/index.json that lists the files *and release dates*. If you kept hold of that file along with the data, you'd always have more information. Let me know if that's of interest to you and I'll look into implementing it.

Comment: Thanks! That's about the best I could hope for. With the current, time-buggy software that this hopes to replace many clients are very reluctant and slow to update (years, sometimes). It would be nice to deal with tzdb changes that occur more frequently in an automatic way. Should anything more drastic happen to the tzdb it can be dealt with as needed.

Comment: @mickeyf: I've just updated the answer very slightly in terms of what will happen for more than 26 releases in a year. It still ends up being sortable though.

Comment: Never say never, and I know that several jurisdictions in Western North America at least are finally seriously considering ditching DST,  but more than 26 releases in a year sounds like an unlikely nightmare.

Comment: @mickeyf: Looking at http://nodatime.github.io/tzvalidate/, it looks like the closest we've come is in 2009 when we got as far as 2009u. That's close enough to z that it's probably not a good idea to bet that it'll never happen...